# Not sure why indexOf() method is not working with my conditional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is going through links in a document to determine if a certain pathname is present. Essentially if it is present `target _self` is set. If not *I'd like* to have the target attribute set to `_blank`

```js
/* 
These are properties of a larger function, 
I am just trying to zero in on the problems.
*/


/* 
These are properties of a larger function, 
I am just trying to zero in on the problems.
*/

var MarkUpChecker = (function iffe() {
    'use strict';
    var URLS = {
            'foo': 'http://foo.com',
            'bar': 'http://bar.com',
            'yay': 'http://www.yay.com'
        },

        publicAPI;

    function getURL() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            return URLS[arguments[i]];
        }
    }
    // function setImgSrc(){

    // }
    publicAPI = {

        addURL: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
                URLS[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
            }
            console.dir(URLS);
            return URLS;
        },
        addTag: function() {
            var doc = document,
                internal_h1 = doc.querySelectorAll('.internal_h1'),
                sheet = doc.createElement('style');
            sheet.innerHTML = '.archive {font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px !important;line-height: 20px !important;color: #333 !important;font-weight: 200 !important;padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;} .archive a {color: #ec008c;display: inline-block;padding: 0 14px;} .file_folder {position: relative;top: 5px;padding: 0 5px;};'
            doc.body.appendChild(sheet);
            if (internal_h1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < internal_h1.length; i++) {
                    internal_h1[i].innerHTML = '<h1>' + internal_h1[i].innerHTML + '</h1>';
                    sheet.innerHTML = 'h1 {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; font-weight: 200!important; font-size: 22px !important; color: #333; margin: 3px 0px 6px; line-height: 24px !important;} .archive {font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px !important;line-height: 20px !important;color: #333 !important;font-weight: 200 !important;padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;} .archive a {color: #ec008c;display: inline-block;padding: 0 14px;} .file_folder {position: relative;top: 5px;padding: 0 5px;};'
                    doc.body.appendChild(sheet);
                }
            }
        },

        searchDoc: function() {
            var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
                emailUrl = /\/img\//,
                newstr = '',
                doc = document,
                container,
                container_links,
                container_images,
                documentTableWrapper,
                docBodyFirstChild;

            if (!doc.getElementById('container')) {
                container = doc.createElement('div');
                container.setAttribute('id', 'avon_rep_container');

                container_links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
                documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
                container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                container.className = 'news';
                docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
                doc.body.insertBefore(container, docBodyFirstChild);

            } else {
                container_links = doc.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');
            }
            container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
            for (var i = 0; i < avon_rep_container_images.length; i++) {
                if (arguments[0] == "foo") {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/news/');
                } else {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/alt_news/');

                }
            }

            for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    link = container_links[j];
                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                        parser = document.createElement('a');
                        parser.href = link.href;

                        newPathName = parser.pathname;
                        link.setAttribute('target', '_self');

                        if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) !== -1) {
                            newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                            newstr = newPathName;

                        } else {
                            newstr = newPathName;

                        }
                        link.href = newstr;

                    } else {

                        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    }
                  
                }

            }
        }
    };
    return publicAPI;
})();
```

What is bedeviling me is this:

```
if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
```

Shouldn't that be the key? if that url is not equal to `-1` that means it's a match so `link.setAttribute('target', '_self');` should be set to the `a tag`.
And if it is equal to `-1` `link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Thanks in advance friends!

**UPDATE**
I added the complete script as requested!

Comment: Why does your `getURL` function iterate its `arguments` but `return` on the first?

Comment: So what does not work?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is block under `if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1)` not being executed? Perhaps the links aren't of the same format and you never get a match. For example `"www.example.com".indexOf("http://www.example.com")`

Comment: @Bergi All the links are getting `target _blank`, I'd like for `target _self` to be applied to the ones which don't pass the `indexOf` test.

Comment: Did you try logging `url` and `link` to console? Your current code looks fine, maybe there is something in the code that you didn't provide.

Comment: @Slayther The function is stripping the pathname like I want to but not applying the `target _self` and I would think it would because of the first if statement...

Comment: Provide us with [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't know what other parts of your code are doing.

Comment: @Slayther I updated the code in its entirety!

Comment: What is `arguments`?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop structure is wrong. You are looping over all links in the container for each url, which will make the effective result for each link that of the last url. Instead, you want something like

```
var urls = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
    urls[i] = getURL(arguments[i]);
}
for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
    link = container_links[j];
    if (urls.every(function(url) {
        return link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1;
    }) {
        // none of the urls matched the link
    } else {
        // at least one of the urls matched the link
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I couldn't get it to work with the rest of my logic. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

The function getURL is incomplete. Lack add the parameter that determines the key that will define the return:

```
function getURL(arg) {
    return URLS[arg];
}
```

if URLS contains the json key, return the link, else, return undefined.

After that, you can continue your logic.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain further?

Comment: Yes.
In that case, you are using "url = getURL(arguments[i]);" to get a url using a key (arguments[i]). But you doesn't define the method getURL() correctly to get the link. The function that I wrote was a sample to define a new function getURL().

*Review the line of code that you have defined the function getURL.